# Are Kotlin functions really first class types?

Tags: kotlin, first-class-functions

Does the fact that this doesn't compile mean that they're not quite first class types?

```
fun foo(s: String): Int = s.length
// This won't compile.
val bar = foo
```

Is there a way to do this without resorting to OO?

Answer (score 7):

> Does the fact that this doesn't compile mean that they're not quite first class types?

No, it doesn't.

In Kotlin, to reference a function or a property as a value, you need to use [callable references](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#callable-references), but it is just a syntax form for [obtaining a value](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type) of a [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types):

```
fun foo(s: String): Int = s.length

val bar = ::foo // `bar` now contains a value of a function type `(String) -> Int`
```

Once you get that value, you are not limited in how you work with it, which is what first-class functions are about.

Comment: What about static methods in Java, e.g. `Files.IsDirectory`? I can't seem to get this to work in the same way.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [reference to the function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type) `::`:

```
fun foo(s: String): Int = s.length

val bar = ::foo
```

And then invoke it:

```
bar("some string")
```